# Is there a way for TWIG to access page's access_control settings in security config file?

Tags: symfony, twig

I new to Symfony.

I want a piece of code only to show on pages that are publicly available. Is it possible for Twig to detect if the page is public?

The page is under `IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY`, but I still want the piece of code to show even if the user is already logged-in.

```
For Example:
www.somesite.com (shows the code, publicly available)
www.somesite.com/login (user login, publicly available, shows code)
//user is not logged in
www.somesite.com/dosomething (only available to logged-in users, code is hidden)
//user goes to the home page, still logged-in
www.somesite.com (must show the code, publicly available)
```

I know I could manually include the code for my public pages, but is there a way to automatically detect if the page is outside the firewall?

Please Help. =)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i guess there is no way to do this. =(

Answer (score 1):

You can hide parts of twig template with a check like so:

```
{% if is_granted('IS_AUTHENTICATED_REMEMBERED') %}
    {# stuff only logged in users can see #}
{% endif %}
```

Comment: Sorry I've modified the question to make it more clearer. hope you got the answer =)

Answer (score 0):

Or check for role IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY

```
{% if is_granted('IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY') %}
    {# stuff only logged in users can see #}
{% endif %}
```

Check the doc here: http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/security.html#retrieving-the-user-object